# MATLAB - discrete 3D stem plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a **discrete** 3D stem plot where `x` and `y` are integers, and `z` is a probability. **Each** pair of `x` and `y` corresponds to a `z` value.

For the ease of demonstration, let's say they have the following correspondences.

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [1 2 3 4 5];
z = [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 ... 0.1]; % totally 25 terms
% 1st z value corresponds to the pair (1st_x_val, 1st_y_val)
```

How may I do it in MATLAB?

Comment: what's not discrete in the plot you just show?

Comment: in the example you give Z should have only 5 elements not 25, because x and y have only 5 elements (1:5)

Comment: @natan This is exactly how this plot is supposed to be different from the attached plot. For each possible pair of `x` and `y`, I have one `z` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [1 2 3 4 5];
z = repmat(0.25,[1 25]);
z = reshape(z,[5 5]);

[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
stem3(x,y,z)
```

Basically with `meshgrid` you are making linear combinations between all x's and all y's, thus making 25 combinations for which you have 25 z's.

[image]

**Edit -1 : Explanation on how to map a linear `z` over a 2D X-Y grid**

**Test Code**

```
x =  1:3;
y = 1:5;
z = 1:15;
z = reshape(z,[numel(y) numel(x)]);

[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
stem3(x,y,z)
xlabel('X -AXIS')
ylabel('Y -AXIS')
```

**Output**

[image]

As one can see how indexing works here - For the first five values, `X` stays the same as `y` varies from 1 to 5 and so on for next 5 values. Thus, if one wants to map a linear `z`  over a 2D X-Y grid, the reshaping would have the first element as number of element in `y` and second would be corresponding number for `x`.

Comment: Let's say (1, 1) corresponds to z(1), (1, 2) corresponds to z(2), (2, 1) corresponds to z(6). How may I do it? Thanks!

Comment: The indexing goes like (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,1),(2,2) for z(1),z(2),z(3),z(4),z(5),z(6),z(7) etc. respectively. So, I guess it should work just like that. Test it out.

Comment: Just plugin your `z` values replacing `z = repmat(0.25,[1 25]);` for that.

Comment: Should I use `z = reshape(z, [numel(x) numel(y)]);` or `z = reshape(z, [numel(y) numel(x)]);`?

Comment: Use the later one - `z = reshape(z, [numel(y) numel(x)]);`

Comment: Exactly! This is what confuses me. Could you please kindly help explain the reason? I am very confused even after reading the documentation.

Comment: See Edit -1. Hope this clarifies all.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this?

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [1 2 3 4 5];
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=0.1*ones(size(X));
stem3(X,Y,Z)
```

I don't understand how the distinction between continuous/discrete is meaningful here though?

Comment: Thanks! The mesh grid is indeed what i have ignored. But what bothers me more is the correspondence relationships. I write all z's as 0.1 simply for the demonstration's sake. They depend on x and y values.

Comment: As long a `Z` is a matrix the same size as `X` and `Y` it's fine. If there is some equation (e.g., `Z=X*Y`) then once you create `X` and `Y` you can write a formula for `Z` (like `Z=X.*Y` for example).